# `echo` in bashrc ignored over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, stdout

If I add a line like `echo 'Hello'` in my `~/.bashrc`, it works, but when I ssh into the machine it simply ignores all `echo` commands. In fact, I think it ignores all of stdout.

If I add a line like `echo 'Err' 2>&1` it does in fact print `Err` before showing the prompt, likewise if I add a `read` in there the shell stops waiting for input before showing me the prompt.

Further commands work fine.

Comment: How are you using `ssh` to connect? Do you start an interactive shell or do you invoke a single command? Does your `~/.bash_profile` source your `~/.bashrc`.  Is this question a duplicate?: [Why does remote Bash source .bash\_profile instead of .bashrc](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/332531)

Comment: Does your ssh client config (typically found at `~/.ssh/config`) have a directive like `LogLevel ERROR`? This could also be implemented via a command line option, if say your environment provides a wrapper function/alias in place of direct access to `ssh` — you would want to use `command ssh` to sidestep something like that.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.ssh/config`. It was working perfectly with `zsh`, now that I changed to `bash` (migrating all dotfiles) is when I got the error.

The `bash` dotfiles are [here](https://github.com/Mendess2526/spell-book/tree/master/runes/bash). They seem to be sourced correctly since all my aliases work fine. The only thing that doesn't is `stdout` during "sourcing".

After the shell prompt is shown typing `source .bashrc` works as expected.